# URL rewrite in IIS 7

Tags: iis, iis-7, url, rewrite

I have a question. I'm using IIS 7 URL rewrite. It works fine, but now I want this:

```
http://www.example.com/http://www.domain.com
```

to be:

```
http://www.example.com/www.domain.com
```

I have no clue on how to do this. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!
Martho

Answer (score 3):

http://learn.iis.net has [a great article](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/) on rewriting urls. They also have [a video](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/506/url-rewrite-module---video-walkthrough/) for those who prefer more personal instruction.

Related

- [Creating rewrite rules for the URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/) on learn.iis.net
- [Rule Templates for the URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/518/rule-templates-for-the-url-rewrite-module/) on learn.iis.net

Answer (score 0):

Also there is software that allows to perform URL rewrite. We use ISAPI_Rewrite for thing like that. For more features i can suggest Helicon Ape.

The rule for your rewrite is going to be:

RewriteRule ^http://([^/]+)$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]